# Es6 class constructor check if arguments is passed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a class with a parameter for its constructor. Can I make sure that a parameter is passed in when instantiating the class?

```
class Test {
    constructor(id) {}
}
```

// would throw some kind of error

```
var test = new Test();
```

// ok

```
var test = new Test(1);
```

Comment: I think the best you can do is check for it in the constructor body. ie: `constructor(id) { if (id === undefined) throw new Error(...); }`

Comment: if(!id) throw new Error()

Comment: Check the value of the parameter?

Comment: @yBrodsky - be careful with the use of `!id`, because id can be `0`.

Comment: oh ye, you are right

Comment: So there's no built in required method right?  I have to check it my self right?

Comment: @LunZhang - JS is not type safe. Maybe you should try typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the constructor if the argument is not defined (=== `undefined`), and if it is throw an error:

```js
class Test {
    constructor(id) {
      if(id === undefined) {
        throw new Error('id is undefined');
      }
    }
} 

new Test();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
constructor(id) {
    if (typeof id != "number")
        throw new Error("missing numeric id argument");
    …
}
```

or

```
constructor(id) {
    if (arguments.length < 1)
        throw new Error("missing one argument");
    …
}
```